# Как запомнить пользователя Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, аутентификация

начал разрабатывать приложение под Android, авторизацию на главном Activity организовал с помощью Firebase, работает!

Но когда я выхожу с приложения или просто проходит какое-то время и по возвращению всё ведёт на главную Activity с регистрацией и логином. Каждый раз логиниться не хочется. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы пользователь если уже логинился, попадал на следующую Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // обозначаем пер.
    Button btn_reg, btn_auth;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference users;
    RelativeLayout main_root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_auth = findViewById(R.id.btn_auth); // поиск кнопки
        btn_reg = findViewById(R.id.btn_reg); // поиск кнопки
        main_root = findViewById(R.id.main_root); // поиск id layout

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = db.getReference("Users");


        btn_reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // кнопка "Зарегистрироваться"
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRegisterWindow(); // показать окно регистрации
            }
        });

        btn_auth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // кнопка "Войти"
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAuthWindow(); // показать окно логина
            }
        });
    }
    private void showRegisterWindow() {
        // Показываем dialog с регистрацией
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); // вызываем билдер диалога
        dialog.setTitle("Зарегистрироваться"); // название диалога
        dialog.setMessage("Введите все данные для регистрации"); // описание диалога
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View register_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_layout, null);
        dialog.setView(register_window);

        final EditText email = register_window.findViewById(R.id.emailField); // поиск email поля
        final EditText password = register_window.findViewById(R.id.passwordField); // поиск password поля
        final EditText name = register_window.findViewById(R.id.nameField); // поиск name поля
        final EditText phone = register_window.findViewById(R.id.phoneField); // поиск phone поля

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Отменить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // кнопка регистрации
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Зарегистрироваться", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(main_root, "Введите Email", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (password.getText().toString().length() < 8) {
                    Snackbar.make(main_root, "Введите пароль (8 символов)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(main_root, "Введите Имя", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(main_root, "Введите номер телефона", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        Userdb user = new Userdb();
                        user.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                        user.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
                        user.setName(name.getText().toString());
                        user.setPhone(phone.getText().toString());

                        users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Snackbar.make(main_root, "Вы успешно зарегистрировались", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        dialog.show(); // вызов dialog
    }
    private void showAuthWindow() {
        // Показываем dialog с авторизацией
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); // вызываем билдер диалога
        dialog.setTitle("Авторизоваться"); // название диалога
        dialog.setMessage("Введите все данные для авторизации"); // описание диалога
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View auth_window = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auth_layout, null);
        dialog.setView(auth_window);

        final EditText email = auth_window.findViewById(R.id.emailField); // поиск email поля
        final EditText password = auth_window.findViewById(R.id.passwordField); // поиск password поля
        // нопка отмены
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Отменить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        // кнопка входа
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Войти", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                // проверка email
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString())) {
                    Snackbar.make(main_root, "Введите Email", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                // проверка пароля
                if (password.getText().toString().length() < 8) { // длина пароля мин. 8 символов
                    Snackbar.make(main_root, "Введите пароль (8 символов)", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                // процесс авторизации
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, general.class)); // запуск general активити
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() { // неудачный вход
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Snackbar.make(main_root, "Ошибка авторизации" + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        });

        }
        });
        dialog.show(); // вызов dialog
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас auth.signOut() нигде в коде не вызывается?

Comment: @Crush Только в другом активити на обработчике OnClickListener, который с этим никак не пересекается. Кнопка выхода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используете Firebase Authentication, то просто проверяете так:

```kotlin
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Показываем данные
} else {
    // Отправляем на авторизацию
}
```

Если раз авторизовался, то currentUser != null. Если удалить и установить приложение заново, то currentUser = null.